# max() implemented with basic operators

Tags: algorithm, math, gdal

I'm wrangling some bad data in a raster image using GDAL with [gdal_calc.py](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_calc.html). I'm trying to clip value `A` at `-100` like this:

```
max(A, -100)
```

However, only basic operators (`+-/*`) and logical operators (`><`, these return 0 or 1) are allowed. Is there a way to implement this? Got as far as returning `0` for values less than `-100`

```
A*(A>-100)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

another one:

```
(A+100)*(A>-100) - 100
```

here the min value will be displaced to 0 to match the lower bound, then displaced back to -100.

Comment: This is faster than the other two with one less multiplication.

Comment: Nice ... `max(a,b) = max(a-b,0)+b = (a-b)*(a-b>0) + b = (a-b)*(a>b) + b`.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe double the trick by changing the expression to `A * (A > -100) + (-100) * (A < -100)`?

Comment: Thanks, that works. Slightly slower than the other answer though. Wish I could accept both

Answer (score 1):

A * (A > - 100) + (-100 * (A < -100))

if A is greater than -100, this reduces to A + 0
if A is less than -100, this reduces to 0 + (-100)